# Module not accepting date type? Is there any other error that I am missing?

Tags: drupal-7, schema, acquia

```
<?php

function kronos_schema() {
  $schema=array();
  $schema['kronos'] = array(

      'description' => 'An example table.',
     'fields' => array(
      'fe_id' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a node.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'Date' => array(
        'description' => 'A field for storing date',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'mytextfield' => array(
        'description' => 'A field for storing short strings of text.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 50,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'mytext' => array(
        'description' => 'A field for storing longer text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('fe_id'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

this code gives me the following error :
Notice: Undefined index: datetime:normal in DatabaseSchema_mysql->processField() (line 205 of C:\Documents and Settings\djeewani-si\Sites\acquia-drupal\includes\database\mysql\schema.inc).
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL COMMENT 'A field for storing an integer number', `mytextfield` VARCHAR' at line 3: CREATE TABLE {kronos} ( `fe_id` INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'The primary identifier for a node.', `Date` NOT NULL COMMENT 'A field for storing an integer number', `mytextfield` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A field for storing short strings of text.', `mytext` TEXT NOT NULL COMMENT 'A field for storing longer text', PRIMARY KEY (`fe_id`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'An example table.'; Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2717 of C:\Documents and Settings\djeewani-si\Sites\acquia-drupal\includes\database\database.inc).

Comment: Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Datetime support was removed from D7 db api - use mysql_type or
>   pgsql_type if you want this functionality.

Try this :

```
'Date' => array(
  'description' => 'A field for storing date',
  'type' => 'datetime',
  'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
  'not null' => TRUE,
)
```

Reference: https://drupal.org/node/159605